# Table and Cell not working in iText 5.5.13

Tags: java, itext

I migrated from iText version 2.1.7 to 5.5.13. I am bound to use iText 5.5.13 in which I have to use Table and Cell like that of `com.lowagie`. I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything other than `PdfPCell` and `PdfPTable`. Kindly suggest some alternative for below code in iText 5.5.13.

```
import com.lowagie.text.Table;
import com.lowagie.text.Cell; 

Cell titleCell = null;
Cell blankCell = null;
Cell noDataCell = null;

Table Outer_dataTable = new Table(1);
Outer_dataTable.setWidth(100f);
Outer_dataTable.setPadding(2);
Outer_dataTable.setSpacing(2);
Outer_dataTable.setBorder(0);
Outer_dataTable.setTableFitsPage(false); 
// Start the new page
document.newPage(); 
PdfPTable titleTable4 = pdfReportUtil.generatePDFTitle(currDate);
titleCell = new Cell(titleTable4);
titleCell.setBorder(0);
Outer_dataTable.addCell(titleCell);
```

Comment: does this code work as you want?

Comment: @devReddit : No, this code works in iText version 2.1.7 but it is not supported in iText version 5.5.13. Kindly suggest equivalent code in version 5.5.13.

Comment: Have you tried using `PdfPTable` and `PdfPCell` instead of `Table` and `Cell`? In which way was the result not satisfying? What do you want to get, what did you get?

Comment: @mkl : methods like setWidth and setPadding etc are not supported by PdfPTable. Kindly help me with the equivalent of above code using PdfPTable.

Comment: I have never used those `Table` and `Cell` classes. The replacement classes `PdfPTable` and `PdfPCell` have been around for 20 years after all! Thus, i don't know which properties of the newer classes correspond with those ones of the older classes. There are some obvious candidates, though. E.g. for `setWidth` there is `setTotalWidth`, `setWidths`, etc. Thus, what have you tried? How did your attempts fail to do what you expected?